# Need to compute formula using data from 3 queries, all from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using NOAA weather data, I am trying to generate a single "score" for each NOAA weather station located in the USA.  The NOAA daily weather data is stored locally in my SQL Server database.

These are the steps I am following to compute the scores:

```
1) For each weather station-

  A) Query / compute average of max temps for July
  B) Query / compute average of max temps for January
  C) Query / compute average of dew points from July

2) Take results from above queries then run it through a formula, generating a score.
```

Ideally this would all be done using SQL.

I can get query and compute each of the steps individually, it's putting them all together where I'm having difficulty.  Here is the query I am using now:

```
SELECT mJan.StationID, mJul.StationID, ROUND((100 - (mJul.AvgMaxTemp) - (mJan.AvgMaxTemp) - (mJul.AvgDewPoint)),2) as MyScore
FROM
    (SELECT StationID, AVG(MaxTemp) as AvgMaxTemp, AVG(MeanDewPoint) as AvgDewPoint FROM dbo.noaasmall WHERE Month=7 AND (MaxTemp<=150) GROUP BY StationID) as mJul,
    (SELECT StationID, AVG(MaxTemp) as AvgMaxTemp, AVG(MeanDewPoint) as AvgDewPoint FROM dbo.noaasmall WHERE Month=1 AND (MaxTemp<=150) GROUP BY StationID) as mJan
ORDER BY mJan.StationID
```

I get an output of various StationID and scores, but it isn't working.

Here is the SQL table format:

[image: SQL Table]

Here is sample output I get from the query:

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: "isn't working" means nothing. Whats wrong with the data you have? For all we know, 10.25 is the right answer. In fact the SQL you've provided doesn't look like it would even run

Comment: @Dale Burrell, I thought "isn't working" was clear enough.  It means I am not getting the expected result.  It was a call for help, I thought that's what these questions were for.

Comment: Not sure why that comment was addressed to me?

Comment: Strange. Originally it showed you as the one who posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT mJan.StationID, mJul.StationID, ROUND((100 - (mJul.AvgMaxTemp) - (mJan.AvgMaxTemp) - (mJul.AvgDewPoint)),2) as MyScore
FROM
(
    SELECT StationID, AVG(MaxTemp) as AvgMaxTemp, AVG(MeanDewPoint) as AvgDewPoint 
    FROM dbo.noaasmall 
    WHERE Month=7 AND (MaxTemp<=150) 
    GROUP BY StationID
) as mJul
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT StationID, AVG(MaxTemp) as AvgMaxTemp, AVG(MeanDewPoint) as AvgDewPoint 
     FROM dbo.noaasmall 
     WHERE Month=1 AND (MaxTemp<=150) 
     GROUP BY StationID
) as mJan
    ON mJul.StationID = mJan.StationID
ORDER BY mJan.StationID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this in a single aggregation query.  However, I'll use a subquery to simplify the calculation:

```
select s.*,
       round(100 - julyAvgMaxtemp - janAvgMaxtemp - julAvgDewPoint, 2) as MyScore
from (select s.StationID,
             avg(case when month = 7 and maxtemp < 150 then maxtemp end) as julyAvgMaxtemp,
             avg(case when month = 1 and maxtemp < 150 then maxtemp end) as janAvgMaxtemp,
             avg(case when month = 7 then meandewpoint end) as julyAvgDewpoint
      from dbo.noaasmall s
      group by s.StationID
     ) s
```